# Declare properties and then define later?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I'm using C++/CLI, trying to declare a class' prototypes in a header file, and then implement them in a cpp file.

In general cpp this seems fairly common, but it doesn't seem to work with the C++/CLI syntax, what am I missing?

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>

using namespace System;

public ref class AClass {

    public:

        static Boolean GetSomething ();    // Compiler is fine with this
        static property Boolean Something { Boolean get (); }    // Compiler doesn't complain about this

};

// Compiler is not cool with this
property Boolean AClass::Something {

    Boolean get () { return true; }

}

// Compiler is fine with this
Boolean AClass::GetSomething () {

    return true;

}
```

I've tried various permutations of the syntax, and nothing seems to work, searching doesn't seem to help either (maybe this isn't widely used anymore?  I find it helps me split up and work with large classes more effectively...).

When I say that the compiler is fine with the prototype of the property, I mean that if I try and compile with the would-be implementation commented out (and the prototype still present), the compiler "succeeds" and then has a heart attack while linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the property getter just like a normal function definition.

```
public ref class AClass 
{
public:
    static property Boolean Something { Boolean get (); }   
};


Boolean AClass::Something::get() 
{
    return true;
}
```